# removing multiple \n in python before sentence tokenizing

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, nltk, data-cleaning

I'm brand new to programming and I am teaching myself out of a book and Stack Overflow.  I'm trying to remove multiple instances of \n in a a chat corpus and then tokenize the sentences.  If I don't remove the \n, the strings look like this:

```
['answers for 10-19-20sUser139 ... hi 10-19-20sUser101 ;)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nI like it when you do it, 10-19-20sUser83\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\niamahotnipwithpics\n\n\n\n10-19-20sUser20 go plan the wedding!']
```

I've tried several different methods like chomps, line, rstrip, etc and none of them seem to work. It could be I am using them wrong.  The whole code looks like this:

```
import nltk, re, pprint
from nltk.corpus import nps_chat
chat= nltk.Text(nps_chat.words())
from nltk.corpus import NPSChatCorpusReader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
chat=nltk.corpus.nps_chat.raw()
soup= BeautifulSoup(chat)
soup.get_text()
text =soup.get_text()
print(text[:40])
print(len(text))
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
sent_chat = sent_tokenize(text)
len(sent_chat)
text[:] = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in text]
print(len(sent_chat))
print(sent_chat[:40])
```

When I use the line method I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\testsubjects\sentencelen.py", line 57, in <module>
text[:] = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in text]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Help?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = 'answers for 10-19-20sUser139 ... hi 10-19-20sUser101 ;)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nI like it when you do it, 10-19-20sUser83\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\niamahotnipwithpics\n\n\n\n10-19-20sUser20 go plan the wedding!'
>>> y = "".join([i if i !="\n" else "\t" for i in x])
>>> z = [i for i in y.split('\t') if i]
>>> z
['answers for 10-19-20sUser139 ... hi 10-19-20sUser101 ;)', 'I like it when you do it, 10-19-20sUser83', 'iamahotnipwithpics', '10-19-20sUser20 go plan the wedding!']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That works if you use the actual text but what if I want to use a definition like text?  Is there something that needs to be added since it doesn't work when you use text but it does work when you use the actual list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I discovered on accident that if you tokenize the text into words first and then sentences the \n disappear!  Thanks for your help!